# How do I fill out Python string templates from a config file?

Tags: python, string, config, keyerror

I have the following template in a config file:

```
"template": "2.1/files/{year:04d}/{month:02d}/{day:02d}/{hour:02d}"
```

And I want to fill out the year, month, day, and hour based on inputs to my function. So far I have tried:

```
test_fill = prefix.format(2021,12,23,14)
```

Where prefix has the template string described above. Trying the above I get:

```
KeyError: 'year'
```

What is the correct to way to modify the string based on my year, month, day, and hour inputs to my function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use keyword arguments to pass values to `format`:

```py
>>> prefix = "2.1/files/{year:04d}/{month:02d}/{day:02d}/{hour:02d}"
>>> prefix.format(year=2021, month=12, day=23, hour=14)
'2.1/files/2021/12/23/14'

>>> (year, month, day, hour) = (2020, 1, 2, 13)
>>> prefix.format(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour)
'2.1/files/2020/01/02/13'
```

Comment: thanks friend! That worked, I completely forgot about kwargs.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the template to:

```py
tmplt = "2.1/files/{:04d}/{:02d}/{:02d}/{:02d}"
print(tmplt.format(2021, 12, 23, 14))
```

which gives:

```
2.1/files/2021/12/23/14
```

You can also retain you template and change how you pass the inputs to format. See the example below with dictionary unpacking:

```py
tmplt = "2.1/files/{year:04d}/{month:02d}/{day:02d}/{hour:02d}"
input = {'year': 2021, 'month': 12, 'day': 23, 'hour': 14}

print(tmplt.format(**input))
```